# Quartz.net - crontrigger for specific days

Tags: c#, quartz.net, crontrigger

I coded a Crontrigger to work for 2 specific days... 14 and 28 of each month. It´s working at the specified time(11:55 pm) but works for every single day :S

```
// Definimos el job de la clase que hereda de la interfaz iJob
            IJobDetail jobCambioClave = JobBuilder.Create<CambioClave>()
                .WithIdentity(LookupItemsTypes.AyA_Password_Changer, "ClosureGroup")
                .Build();

            ITrigger conTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .ForJob(jobCambioClave)
                .WithIdentity("PassWordAyAChangerTrigger", "ClosureGroup")
                .WithCronSchedule("0 55 23 14-28 * ?") 
                .StartNow()
                .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobCambioClave, conTrigger);

            scheduler.Start();
```

If you have an idea why is this happening please I'll appreciate it, I´ve been testing a lot of expressions for the .WithCronSchedule parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a comma in the day part of the expression to specify range. Like this:

`0 55 23 14,28 * ?`

Have a look at [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/), it is very useful for testing cron expressions.